# How to extract javascript dynamic data from a web page

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c

In my MAC OS X application, I need to extract, from a web page, numeric values which are regularly updated via a javascript. When I load the url, I get the html source without the values I am looking for. 
I found in WebKit Programming Guide the following example which, may be, is the solution :
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];

Using Interface Builder, I dragged a WebView from the Library into a window but failed to declare the outlet in the controller :
IBOutlet WebView *webView;
syntax error : unknown name view WebView

I opened a fresh new project, added webkit framework to the linked libraries and the same error again.
As I am new to objective-c I am probably missing something very basic and help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to "name" the WebView object to "webView" (and upgrade Xcode to 4 if you are still using Interface Builder!). It's in the attributes, Menu Item Identifier (iirc) - probably set to "automatic". Change it to `webView`

Comment: I am using XCode 4. I named the WebView as you recommended in the identity inspector but I had another bug I just found : the import directive for WebKit was missing. Thanks a lot, I should make progress